# Save entire model but load weights only

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning

I have defined a deep learning model `my_unet()` in tensorflow. During training I set `save_weigths=False` since I wanted to save the entire model (not only the wieghts bu the whole configuration). The generated file is `path_to_model.hdf5`.

However, when loading back the model I used the earlier version (I forgot to update it) in which I first called the model and then load the model using:

```
model = my_unet()

model.load_weights(path_to_model.hdf5)
```

Instead of simply using: `model = tf.keras.models.load_model(path_to_model.hdf5)` to load the entire model.

Both ways of loading the model and the weights provided the same predictions when run in some dummy data and there were no errors.

My question is: Why loading the entire model using `model.load_weights()` does not generate any problem? What is the structure of the hdf5 file and how theese two ways of loading exactly work? Where can I find this information?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can please see the documentation here for any future reference: http://davis.lbl.gov/Manuals/HDF5-1.8.7/UG/03_DataModel.html

Comment: So does that mean that no matter if you save the entire model or just the weights, the hdf5 file structure is exactly the same with the sole difference that in the former you will have the additional information regarding the optimizer, metrics... whereas in the latter these fields will be blank?